# How to share code between 2 classes that have the same root class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, oop, inheritance

I have created a custom class called `RCTextField`, whose purpose is to create an `NSTextField` with rounded corners (thus `RC...`).

This `RCTextField` inherits from `NSTextField` and overrides the `drawRect:` method in order to create its own rectangle with rounded corners.

Now, I want to do the same thing for `NSSecureTextField`, that is, have a way to make it have rounded corners. I can't just make it inherit `RCTextField`, because that one doesn't have any *secure* implementation for text that `NSSecureTextField` has.

And if I inherit from `NSSecureTextField`, I'd have to rewrite all the `drawRect:` implementation again.

An option I thought about would be to have an `RCBaseTextField` class which contains a static method called `drawRect:forNSTextField:withParams:`, and call that one in the `drawRect:` of `RCTextField` and `RCSecureTextField`. However, that seems a bit hackish, and it feels like there could be a better OOP way to do this in Objective-C.

So, what would be the best/sanest/software-engineering-"esquest" way to share the draw-rounded-corners code from `RCTextField` between an `RCTextField` and an `RCSecureTextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot make an Objective-C inherit behavior from more that one other class. I think providing a function (using a Object-Oriented language doesn't prevent from using functions when they are appropriate) that will be invoked by both `drawRect:` implementation is the simpler way.

Or you may just ignore `NSSecureTextField` and make `RCSecureTextField` inherit from `RCTextField`. Then implement the class method `cellClass` to return `NSSecureTextFieldCell` and you should get the same exact features as `NSSecureTextField`.

```
@interface RCSecureTextField : RCTextField
@end

@implementation RCSecureTextField
+ (Class)cellClass { return [NSSecureTextFieldCell class]; }
@end
```

Comment: I wonder if by implementing +cellClass alone, his RSSecureTextField class will have all he needs to behave as NSSecureTextField (I don't know the details of NSSecureTextField).

Comment: According to `NSSecureTextField` documentation: `NSSecureTextField` uses `NSSecureTextFieldCell` to implement its user interface.

Comment: I have tried to do this programmatically, but it does not work. If the cell is NSTextFieldCell in Interface Builder, it will keep on being NSTextFieldCell even if I say in `cellClass` that it should return `[NSSecureTextFieldClass class]`. However, this does work when I change the cell's type in Interface Builder to NSSecureTextFieldCell...

Comment: Yes, the `cellClass` is only used when creating a text view with `initWithFrame:`. When the text view is created in Interface Builder, its cell is archived alongside in the XIB/NIB.

Comment: Functions are not OO. Use composition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: What's the point of adding a new class and instantiating a new object for any text field when you can use a good old function? If we needed to encapsulate data, i wouldn't argue. But in this particular case, a function is the simplest solution. OO is great, but don't forget there is a *C* in *Objective-C*.

Comment: Functions are for C, methods are for Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

I find that object composition helps with situations like this. Move all your methods that are shared into a separate class and then have both `RCTextField` and `RCSecureTextField` insatiate your helper class and call the methods appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Make a C function with this prototype:

```
void drawTextFieldRoundRect(NSTextField* instance, CGRect rect);
```

declared in a file named (say) `TextFieldRounded.h` and defined in the corresponding `TextFieldRounded.m` (contains no classes, just this C function. But make it .m so you can use Objective-C syntax).

Inside this function you perform your custom drawing. You have access to 'self' through the parameter `instance`.

Next, in `RCTextField` you implement `-drawRect:` like this:

```
#import "TextFieldRounded.h"

- (void) drawRect:(CGRect) rect
{
    drawTextFieldRoundRect(self, rect);
}
```

(and do the same for `RCSecureTextField`)

Not the most elegant, I know...

**Option 2:** IF you are using rounded text fields **only**, you can add a category on NSTextField and NSSecureTextField should inherit the 'rounded' behavior. But if you want both rounded **and** normal text fields, it can't do.

Comment: There's no special handling for ARC needed here.

Comment: You are right; the (only) receiving end only manipulates an object which is a function parameter. I deleted that line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a case for dependency injection (note: NSSecureTextField inherits from NSTextField):

```
@interface RCTextField : NSObject {
  NSTextField *textField
}
- (id) initWithTextField:(NSTextField *)_textField;

@end
```

And then just expose whatever functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to subclass `NSTextFieldCell`, not the controls. I would subclass `NSSecureTextFieldCell` and use it in both controls; from the drawing perspective the only difference is the value of `echosBullets` property.